# Kapacitor - Editing A Metric value with a tick script

Tags: time-series, task, influxdb, kapacitor

in a simple tick script, how can i query points and edit some key/values ?

i have this tick script:

```
     var data = batch
         |query(''' SELECT * FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."cpu" ''')
             .period(5m)
             .every(10s)
             .groupBy(*)
         |influxDBOut()
             .database('telegraf)
             .retentionPolicy('autogen')
             .measurement('modified_data)
```

that queries some data, i want to change the CPU field on each point and add 5 to its value.

how can i do that ?
thanks.
Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you change the fields *inside* CPU measurement.

For example, let's say your CPU measurement contains a field named **time_idle**, then you just have to insert an "eval" node before the output node.

```
 var data = batch
     |query(''' SELECT * FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."cpu" ''')
         .period(5m)
         .every(10s)
         .groupBy(*)
     |eval(lambda: "time_idle" + 5)
         .as('time_idle_plus_5')
     |influxDBOut()
         .database('telegraf')
         .retentionPolicy('autogen')
         .measurement('modified_data')
```

Would be a good idea to read more about **eval** node [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/nodes/eval_node/) and about TICKScript nodes in general.